# Codeigniter ajax form validation in modal not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to validate my form which is in bootstrap modal. But all time `validation_errors()` returning empty string. I am using Codeigniter 3 and HMVC.

here is my ajax code

```
$('#add_unload').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var carrier_type = $.trim($('#carrier').val());
        var truck_plateno = $.trim($('#truck_plateno').val());

        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'pre_unload/add',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                carrier_type : carrier_type,
                truck_plateno:truck_plateno
            }

        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);

        });
    });
```

and here is my controller's `add` method

```
public function add() {

 if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        die('wrong');
    }
    $carrier_type = $this->input->get('carrier_type', TRUE);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('truck_plateno', 'Truck Plate', 'required');

    if ($carrier_type == 'O') {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('another_filed', 'XXXX', 'required');

    } else {
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('another_filed', 'XXXX', 'required');
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        echo json_encode(array('err' => validation_errors()));
        return;
    }

}
```

`var_dump($this->form_validation->run());return;` always return false and `validation_errors()` return empty string. I have tried this too `$this->form_validation->run($this)` still no luck. `My_form_validation.php` also ok in library

** I have loaded `form_validation` library in construct

Any IDEA?

Comment: try to put else on your if statement. like else echo something. then check if it goes to else.

Comment: why ELSE? need. There are no way to go in ELSE block because `$this->form_validation->run()` always return FALSE

Comment: Then you can also try to replace your `===` to `==` .

Comment: Make sure you already declared the truck_plateno variable inside your add function before giving it rules. It will always return false because CI didn't know what is truck_plateno inside your form rules.

Comment: @claudios These should not be issue you are saying. Already used in many project